# Deploy group in marathon

Tags: docker, marathon

I am trying to deploy gitlab using marathon.
In development, i was using a docker-compose.yml, which included mariadb and redis in two dependances container.

I saw the marathon [sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mesosphere/marathon/master/examples/Group.json) for creating groups.

I am trying to adapt so it look like the same as the docker-compose.yml

Only one think, I don't see how I can link container together.

Answer (score 0):

You don't link Docker containers with Marathon. You use service discovery such as Mesos-DNS. Have a look at this [end-to-end example](https://mesosphere.com/blog/2015/06/21/web-application-analytics-using-docker-and-marathon/).